# Efficient way to get frequency distribution of values in a large MySql table

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, frequency-distribution, large-data

I have two tables viz. **Total_Data** and **Distinct_S1**.

**Total_Data** has 3.5 million rows. Fields: "S1", "S2", "S3", "S4"

**Distinct_S1** has 1 million rows. Fields: "S1", "frequency".
"S1" of **Distinct_S1** consists of all distinct values which occur in "S1" of **Total_Data**.

Task at hand:
"frequency" of **Distinct_S1** for S1 = 'xxyy' (suppose) should consist of the number of times 'xxyy' occurs in **Total_Data**.

I used the following query from within a python script(MySQLdb imported) to accomplish the Task at hand:

```
cur.execute("update Distinct_S1 set frequency=(select count(*) from Total_Data where S1='%s') where S1='%s'"%(S1_val, S1_val)
```

The above query works fine but it seems to take a lot of time. Is there any other faster way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multi-table update syntax with a join to update all rows at once. See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) for the syntax.

But a much easier way is to also insert all the values in the table directly without first populating it with the distinct values.

```
INSERT INTO Distinct_S1 (S1, frequency)
SELECT S1, COUNT(*)
FROM Total_Data
GROUP BY S1
```

Comment: I ran your above query. After 13 minutes, it's done! Thanks a lot! P.S. I guess updates are more expensive than inserts and 'python-to-mysql-to-python transition' might have taken a lot of time.